# In a collection, is a lookup performed every time I access it by index, or is that compiled away?

Tags: c#, collections

```
List<Apple> apples = GetApples();
Console.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}", apples[0].Name, apples[0].Color, apples[0].Size));
```

Is the lookup performed every time I get the object by its index, or does that get compiled away?

Is the following more performant?

```
List<Apple> apples = GetApples();
var first = apples[0];
Console.Write(string.Format("{0}: {1}, {2}", first.Name, first.Color, first.Size));
```

Obviously in this trivial example, called once, it wouldn't be an issue worth worrying about. I'm curious because the actual code I'm writing will be called many times in a loop.

Comment: Those two code blocks are not equivalent.  One gets the apple at index `i`, the other gets the first apple.  If the performance of this code is in fact in need of improving (however unlikely), deciding between index-based access or LINQ is important.

Comment: You are correct of course; I'll modify it to access the zeroeth index, which was my intent.

Comment: It goes without saying that you could always make your own collection and implement a terrible indexer that does something totally dumb :)

Comment: In the workings, they are the same except `First` casts out the `IEnumerable` to a `IList` and then return's the index; either way, the search happens every time using the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code for `List<T>` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs). You can see where the "indexer" is defined starting where it says `public T this[int index]` (currently on line 145). You can see that it does a check to see if the specified index is out of range, and then simply returns the value from the underlying array.

So the two pieces of code are not exactly equivalent. That indexer block is executed each time you call `apples[0]`. In the case of `List<T>`, it's not a huge performance difference between the two - doing a quick integer comparison (the range check) three times is not terribly expensive.

HOWEVER, other classes besides List may not be so efficient with their indexers, so it's best to know what kind of performance you're dealing with if it matters in your situation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how the collection is implemented. `List<T>` is backed by an array so it has array-like access.

I believe several of the non-deferred LINQ operations have shortcuts for certain collections, so calling `.First()` would have the same effect as `apples[0]`.

I can't speak to how the C# compiler lowers to the call, but I would suspect that it would call the indexer everytime to invoke any (unfortunate) side-effects. If there aren't any side-effects, I doubt it would improve performance much. CPUs are really effective at branch predictions and caching.

Comment: Yeah, my question was poorly phrased at first. My concern is not with the performance of LINQ's First() vs. conventional index access; it's about whether multiple calls on an index each result in a separate search of the collection, or would the compiler help out somehow. The second case, with the 'defensive' copy, would obviously eliminate any nasty changes behind the scenes, but I'm asking if it's a more performant approach in particular.

Comment: @DavidMorgan my last paragraph should answer tat.

Comment: Thanks; I suspect it calls it each time as well, but I realized I don't really have solid reasoning behind that. I'll hold out a bit for an answer from a compiler shaman. I upvoted you but it won't show it because I'm a filthy noob.

Comment: You are confusing people with the term "searched", it's accessed, it goes to the list and picks the element. That is some calls, but there is not searching involved. Yes storing the access is generally preferred, but it's not necessarily getting faster, cause optimization might do exactly the same automatically for you. But you cannot rely on that. (daniel explained already, sometimes other words help understand the same thing better).

Comment: @Holger that’s why i said it depends on the collection type

Comment: Maybe the question was modified, there is no collection, no interfaces no LINQ involved in this Question. It's pure native List<T>. And First() and only that, is almost O(1), same speed for any enumerable.

Comment: @Holger I see your point: 'search' is definitely not the right term; I meant 'lookup'. Also, yes, the question was modified; the original version used First(), which was confusing and wrong. Unfortunately my question-asking skills have gotten in the way of the answer I'm looking for.